# My Mac network location script is broken

Tags: python, macos, networking, python-2.7

I am starting to learn python and I decided to start with what I though was a simple script but I guess not. All I want to do is return what current network location I am using on my mac. Every time I run it, it gives me back the correct location but then when I try to change it, nothing happens. I don't know what I am doing wrong so here is my code. I really hope some one can help me. This script is unique to MACS btw. I know that the "scselect" is built in but I wanted to see if it could be done with Python. The code below is rough I know but as I learn I will make it better. I am using Python 2.7.

```
import subprocess

loc = "scselect"
srn = "scselect SRN"
home = "scselect HOME"

a = subprocess.check_output(loc, shell=True)

print "\n##### NETWORK SELECTION #####"
print "\nYour current location is set to \n\n%s" % a

choice = raw_input("Please select what location you want to change to: ")

b = subprocess.Popen(srn, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
c = subprocess.Popen(home, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

choice = int(choice)

if choice == 1:
    print "\nSwitching to HOME...\n"
    c
elif choice == 2:
    print "\nSwitching to SRN...\n"
    b
else:
    print "\nShutting down...\n"
```

Comment: "[...] but then when I try to change it, nothing happens." When you say that nothing happens, do you mean that after you input your choice you get no output from the script?

Comment: @user2495187: I do not understand that sentence either. I think you mean that `subprocess.check_output` works as expected, but `subprocess.Popen` lines do not seem to change the network. Am I right?

Comment: @KyleG. That is the odd part I do get output like so: Switching to HOME...

SCPreferencesCommitChanges() failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run *both* `scselect` commands first, then only display the *output* of one of the commands.

By the time you come to `if choice == 1`, etc. both `b` and `c` have already been set and have captured the output of the commands. Both `scselect SRN` **and** `scselect HOME` have been run, with the last one undoing anything the first command achieved.

Move the `subprocess` calls into the `if` statements:

```
if choice == 1:
    print "\nSwitching to HOME...\n"
    output = subprocess.Popen(home, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print output
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH Martijn Pieters. It works!!!. Once one question I have now when it runs the command I get a hex code like so <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10a58fc10>. Is it possible to have it not print that?

Comment: @user2495187: You are printing the `Popen()` return object. If you wanted *just* the output, use `subprocess.check_output()` instead again.